# how to remove rows from dataframe in r (different situation)

Tags: r

So I want to remove the first row in the data frame. my code is like

`reddot.info<-reddot.info[-1,]`

But then i find i can not view this data frame. i figure out the reason. because when i run code

`reddot.info[1,]`

if appears as 
     `Num Product_names URL`
    `1  NA Product Names URL`
which means that if i use this code i will also remove the column names.
so what should i do to remove the first row in stead of removing the column names and first row together.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you include `dput(reddot.info)` so that we could understand your problem better ?

Answer (score 4):

You probably don't have column names to begin with because removing the first row like that doesn't remove the column names.

```
colnames(reddot.info) <- reddot.info[1,]
reddot.info <- reddot.info[-1,]
```